# DB projection issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a project on Laravel 5.4
I have 3 tables : CV, Country and City.
User creates a CV. User have to introduce his country and city.
So, 1 Country for Many CV.
1 Country has Many Cities.

```
CV (Many) -> (1) Country (1) <- City (Many).
```

> CV Table :  ID, country_id 
>  Country Table :  ID, name 
>  City
>   Table :  ID, name, country_id

For me, it's seems that CV should have a relationship with `City` table as well. 
I need this kind of relationship, because I want to add a `search-autocomplete`. So, when user is choosing a country, `search-autocomplete` will show a list of countries by `input value`, then, when he will choose a `City` input, it will call a `Ajax request` that will give a dropdown with all cities associated with this country.

Also, I need this kind of relationship for my search. I will have a page for searching for CV's, and available filters will be: `Country and City`.

So, I can't understand first, how to save and get the `CV's city`. And do I really need this kind of relationship? `Country and City` table must have that relationship, to be sure that autocomplete will show only cities associated with this country, but how to save on `CV` table value of chosen city?

Comment: you may need models and controllers

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017 you may watch this,
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/15